Execution of Gradle Tasks and find out why are they executed
I'm currently doing a Udemy Course to learn Kotlin and I've a Question about Gradle and Tasks. I've tried HILT and had to add kapt to my Project (empty project with jetpack-compose).
My app/build.gradle.kts looked like this:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    id("io.objectbox")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}


dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.2.0")
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.51.1")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.51.1")
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}

After some time I decided to remove it again cause the Buildtime increased and it wasn't necessary anymore for the course.
My Problem is now, that gradle still executes tasks like: kaptGenerateStubsDebugAndroidTest, kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin, kaptReleaseKotlin, kaptReleaseUnitTestKotlin and more
How can I find out why these tasks are executed? Probably because of Compose? I've set up a new project and those aren't there.
Running ./gradlew help --task [OneOfTheMentioned] does not really help:
> Task :help
Detailed task information for kaptReleaseKotlin

Path
     :app:kaptReleaseKotlin

Type
     KaptWithoutKotlincTask (org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask)

Options
     --rerun     Causes the task to be re-run even if up-to-date.

Description
     -

Group
     -

kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin makes the build twice as long it would be and Build Analyzer(which warns me about it as well) says:
 Reason task ran: Value of input property 'compilerOptions.freeCompilerArgs' has changed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'

Things I already did:
sync with files
clean
rebuild
deleted .gradle Folder

Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 1 on Ubuntu Mate

After some research I've found a solution.
./gradlew app:dependencies [app was in my case the module name]

Even more information could be get with:
plugins {
    id("org.barfuin.gradle.taskinfo") version "2.2.0"
}

and then
./gradlew tiTree [taskName]

